# How to redirect page after using the DELETE method in express?

Tags: node.js, express, http, mongoose

I'm a newbie in Nodejs and I'm coding a to-do app as a practical exercise. I'm having a problem that I cannot return to my index page "/" after using the DELETE method in Express. I use the `deleteMany()` of Mongoose to delete my docs, however after deleted all of those docs I couldn't return to the "/" page, the system threw an error in the console:

> DELETE http://localhost:3000/ 404 (Not Found)

although using `res.redirect("/")` is fine with POST method. I've found a guy with the same problem as mine on Stack Overflow, but his solutions are not working in my app. Another solution of him is using pure Javascript to redirect from the client, however I want to do this job in the severside.

My files:
routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {

var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
var db = require("./db");

app.get("/", function(req,res,next) {
    db.task.find()
    .then(tasks => {
        res.render("index", {tasks: tasks})
    });
})
```

}

controller.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
const routes = require("./routes.js");
const apiRoutes = require("./api.js");
app.use(function(req,res,next) {
    console.log(`GET ${req.url}`);
    next();
})

app.use("/api", apiRoutes);
routes(app);
```

}

api.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
var db = require("./db");    

router.post("/post", urlencodedParser, function(req,res) {
    new db.task({"name": req.body.item, "status": "incompleted"})
    .save(err => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(req.body.item);
    });
    res.redirect("/");
}).delete("/delete/:item", function(req,res) {
    var result = [];
    var item = req.params.item;
    //Config the url task to its original name
    var delTask = item.replace(/\-/g," ").replace(/;/g,"-");

    //Logging out the deleted task
    db.task.find({"name": delTask}).then((foundTasks) => {
        foundTasks.forEach(function(tasks){
            var removedDoc = {"name": tasks.name, "Object_Id": tasks._id};
            result.push(removedDoc);
        })
    })
    db.task.deleteMany({"name": delTask}, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Removed items: ", result);
        
    })
    res.redirect("/");
})



module.exports = router;
```

You don't have to worry about the db.js file, because it just help me to create mongoose schema and completely do nothing with http or express. And finally the controller.js will be required in the app.js.

Comment: Can you add more code of your routes? Add all the routes that you have created.

Comment: ok. I'm afraid that many people would found my code is messed up and hard to see through the problem. But if it's okay to you then I'll update it and hope you could read those messy codes:))

Comment: How are you calling the `DELETE` method? With what client? A browser can't do `DELETE` requests without the help of javascript, so this is relevant.

Comment: Oh sorry, that is my mistake. Actually I have another script file for creating the DELETE requests with jQuery. The request will be sent when the user hit the DELETE button on my page. `$.ajax({ type: 'DELETE', url: '/api/delete/' + tasknamewanttodelete;});`